# Creating a bootable .iso file from MINIX OS build

Tags: operating-system, kernel, minix

So i have downloaded the source code of Minix3 from git following the instructions given on their page

```
git clone git://git.minix3.org/minix minixsrc
```

I am using ubuntu 16.0.4 and I cross compiled the code from the linux terminal

```
sh build.sh -mi386 -O ../build -U distribution
```

Now I have a folder named 'build' which has the built OS.

**So, How do I create a bootable image from this folder so that i can write it to a CD/USB and boot my PC in MINIX**